# How to run functions using lists as the parameters?

Tags: python

So say I have two lists,

`a=[x,y,....z]` and `b=[x1,y1,...z1]`

and a function that has parameters of these two lists:

```
def examplefunction(a,b)
```

How could I make it so that the function uses the first items in lists a and b, then the second items in lists a and b, until the end of the list? (And each list has the same number of items)

Would I do something like:

```
def main():
    for i in range(len(a)):
        examplefunction(a[i],b[i])
```

with i being the 1st, 2nd, ... nth item in the list.

Comment: thanks for the replies but I'm not really getting the answer I am looking for. I have two lists a,b that need to be put in my function examplefunction(a,b). However, I need to find a way to call the function using the first item of a and b, then the second item, until the end of the list.

Comment: user3's answer below will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `zip` to access 2 list items simultaneously:

```
for firstlistitem,secondlistitem in zip(a,b):
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not sure what you're asking for, but 
Your example function would look like this:

```
def examplefunction(a,b):
    list_s = len(a)
    for i in range(list_s):
        item_a = a[i]
        item_b = b[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the items by index, though user3's solution is more elegant.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    print value, b[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[examplefunction(aa, bb) for (aa, bb) in zip(a,b)]
```

would produce a list of the results, or use () instead of [] to get a generator.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on user3's answer I created a quick demo function to demonstrate that it works.

```
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     print('{} - {}'.format(a, b))
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> l
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> for a, b in zip(l, lst):
...     foo(a, b)
... 
10 - 1
9 - 2
8 - 3
7 - 4
6 - 5
5 - 6
4 - 7
3 - 8
2 - 9
1 - 10
```